# I want to create a basic attribute system with Python (classes and def statements)

Tags: python, function, class

I'm a fledgling coder starting out with Python, and am trying to create a simple attribute system capable of interacting with other sections of the program (e.g. def statements). Based on the meager amount of knowledge I currently have of the Python language, I'm assuming the best way to accomplish this task is to use a class coupled with def statements to create commands and actions relevant to the class in question. Whenever I try to run my code, I end up with this error:

```
    if petname['hungry'] == True:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Again, I have a very limited amount of knowledge right now, so I don't know if my program is close to being usable, or if it's just useless garbage. I'll post my code here. I'd greatly appreciate some corrective criticism; or, heck, if someone could correctly rewrite it for me, that'd be great!

Here's the code I wrote. Let me know if anymore info is necessary to give a comprehensive answer:

```
petname = 'Dog'

class petname (object):
    attributes = {'health': 20, 'attack': 4, 'size': 5, 'hunger': True}

def feed(petname):
    if petname['hungry'] == True:
        petname['hungry'] = False
        petname['size'] = petname['size'] + 1
        print("{0} happily gobbles down the treat!".format(petname))
    else:
        print("{0} is not hungry.".format(petname))

if petname['hungry'] == True:
    print("{0} is hungry! Feed it something!".format(petname))
    input()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! One vocabulary tip: a "def statement" is called a function, and a function tied to a class is called a method.  You need to call `petname.attributes`, as that is the named attribute of the `petname` class, then index into that attribute with the correct key, e.g., `attributes={...'hunger': True}` vs `['hungry'] == True`.

Comment: It may be worth doing a classes/methods tutorial like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp), as you are missing some key features of python classes, like `self` and an `__init__` method, in addition to the naming conventions (classes are named in CamelCase, not lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the name `petname` across your code, and expecting it to mean different things even in the same context.  Your `petname` class doesn't make much sense, as the single `pername.attributes` dictionary will be shared among the instances of all `petname` objects.

Below, I organize the `Pet` object to have attributes, use inheritance to establish default values for dogs, and make `feed` a method of the `Pet` class:

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, size, hunger):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.size = size
        self.hunger = hunger
    def feed(self):
        if self.hunger:
            self.hunger = False
            self.size += 1
            print("{0} happily gobbles down the treat!".format(self.name))
        else:
            print("{0} is not hungry.".format(petname))

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, 20, 4, 5, True)

spot = Dog("Spot")
spot.feed()
# Spot happily gobbles down the treat!
```

Comment: Wow, guys! Fast answers! I really, really appreciate the help you guys gave me. It was very helpful. I suppose part of the problem was my lack of basic knowledge regarding classes and functions. The tutorial that G. Anderson suggested was extremely beneficial to me.

Comment: ...Also, thanks for being nice about my obviously ultra-noob question.